# Looking for a story about a warrior who fights a octopus monster and beats it making noise

Tags: story-identification, comics, robert-e-howard, sword-and-sorcery

I remember this story from about 1970. It probably was a comic, but there's a chance that it was an ilustrated novel. Style and aesthetics were similar to Conan the barbarian.

A warrior enters to a castle (or may be a tower). Inside there is a octopus-like monster who fights him. The monster can't bear noises and the warrior beats him hitting a gong, or may be a bell, that was by the gate.

I've googled for Conan, but I found nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reference to Conan had me thinking and I had a rememberance of this too from reading the story but it was Robert E. Howard's *other* barbarian, Kull of Atlantis.

A few minutes googling found this page on "[**The Skull of Silence**](http://www.gwthomas.org/theskullofsilence.htm)"

> Originally appeared in King Kull 1967.
>
> Plot: Kull hears of an ancient vault where the embodiment of all Silence was said to be held. He is fascinated and takes a group of men to see the tower and vault where Raama was said to have trapped it. He (foolishly) cuts open the vault, allowing the complete silence of the universe to escape. By accident he **strikes a gong** set near the vault and its weak sound forces Silence back a little. He strikes it over and over, forcing Silence back into the vault. Unlike Raama, Kull does not stop at trapping it but goes on striking the gong until he destroys Silence, which dies with a scream.
>
> "The Skull of Silence" appeared in ***Creatures on the Loose #10 (March 1970)*** and was adapted by Roy Thomas and drawn by Bernie Wrightson.

[image]

[image]